# Asp.net slow first load per user

Tags: iis-7

I have a website set up with in IIS 7 with HTTPS, and every time a user access it for the first time the load time is about 15 sec.

THIS IS NOT the compile/warm up "problem" described for instance her: [Slow first page load on asp.net site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102609/slow-first-page-load-on-asp-net-site) 
I know about that "problem" and I also have that, but that is of course expected and not the issue here.

Since it's not when the application loads first time since recycle/start. If I open another browser and access it after doing it first in another browser then it takes the same amount of time. So it seems every time a session is started, that's when the delay happens. All following requests from the same user/browser is as quick as expected.

This is for an admin interface site I have and I use asp.net membership. Although the delay happens even before the user have logged in. So I'm not sure if that is the culprit.

I am a bit unsure where to look for killing the delay. I am running session state in process. With cookies.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a little more information. Enable trace and track how long each step takes. You could also use Wireshark and have a look at the traffic between the client/server. If there is a big gap in traffic you can see something is hanging at the servers end. If you see constant traffic perhaps you have to much going on with your landing page. Other simple things to do would be to enable dynamic caching/compression on the server to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Warm it up...

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/688/using-the-iis-application-warm-up-module/