# ASP.NET & IIS 7.0 -- HTTPS Site Warmup Script

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 site on IIS 7.0 that is having first time load issues described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102609/slow-first-page-load-on-asp-net-site).

I've done some testing, and can confirm that it's only the first load of the page that is slow; every subsequent page loads normally.  After googling around for this, I found a "warmup" script that can send an HTTP request the first time after the app pool is recycled, and this seems to fix the problem. BUT, I'm not sure if it will work when I force set the page to use only HTTPS/SSL?

The script I'm currently using is as follows:

```
Dim website1

website1 = "http://<website domain>/Auth/Login.aspx"

Function WarmUpSite(strURL)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim objHTTP 
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHTTP.Send
    If Err.Number=0 And objHTTP.Status=200 Then 
        Hget=strURL & " has been warmed up successfully at:  "&Date()&"  "&Time() 
    Else
        Hget=strURL & " found error at:  "&Date()&"  "&Time()
    End If
    Set objHTTP = Nothing
    'Section for writing into a text file
    Const FOR_APPENDING = 8
    strFileName = "C:\WarmUpLog.txt"
    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTS = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFileName,FOR_APPENDING)
    objTS.WriteLine Hget
End Function

WarmUpSite(website1)
```

So my question is how I would make this work if the website I'm warming up is a login page that will be an HTTPS address, not HTTP?  My apologies if this is a dumb question, I do relatively little web work.

Comment: What file would this script go in? Or, maybe, what would cause this script to be run if the application pool is reset, and the site won't build it again until someone visits the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently it just involved changing the value of website1 to an HTTPS url.

;)